# Wcf web service

Tags: web-services, wcf

I have a WCF web servive which I have hosted on same network PC(not where client application run). When I try to add service reference to client application the following error is raised...

Note: I can access the web service through web browser where client application runs

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> There was an error downloading 'ipaddress/uploads/TransferService.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
>
> The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.
>
> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: [/ipaddress/uploads/TransferService.svc].
>
> Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service ipaddress/uploads/TransferService.svc.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
>
> The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not supported by service 
>   ipaddress/uploads/TransferService.svc.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
>   The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..
>   If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Anyone please help in this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your target framework is 4.5 or higher, you can try to download service as a [single WSDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456789(v=vs.110).aspx) — just append `?singleWSDL` to the URI when requesting metadata from the service.

Comment: but still i get d error There was no endpoint listening at http://valez-pc/uploads/TransferService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details

Comment: @KathabSp Make sure that your `TransferService.svc` is properly configured. Check `system.serviceModel` section and make sure that endpoint for `TransferService.svc` is present there.

Comment: yes its working fine now..my endpoint was empty..thanks Sergey@@@